# Strange bug when switching from an ortographic projection to a perspective projection

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'll try to keep this as short as possible, and if there's any info you need you'll have to ask for it because the source is a bit too big to post here.

I have a strange bug when trying to change the projection currently in use. Ortographic works flawlessly but when I switch to using XMMatrixPerspectiveLH, my primitives are no longer visible on the screen. I've made sure the primitives aren't on the far plane, I've disabled culling completely, I've made sure my camera is looking in the right direction and that the primitives aren't behind me but still nothing.

What's even stranger is that XMMatrixPersectiveFovLH seems to work without problems too.

Anyways, I know this is a really broad question but I hope you'll atleast be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Would help if you could post the `XMMatrixPerspectiveLH` and `XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH` could with your exact arguments.

Comment: Draw something using perspective space coordinates, see if you can see it in perspective.  Then switch back to ortographic and see if you can see it.  Maybe draw something that goes from known visible objects to projective origin in ort view?